# Group pandas dataframe by a outside column

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
db = pd.read_csv('17base.csv')
order = pd.read_csv('order.csv')
db = db.groupby(db['code'])['r'].mean()
```

and the two dataframe is just like the table I drew here. But this code don't work, since I want to group every 50 "codes" here

I have a dataframe like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqeLd.png). I want to first group the code by the order of another [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3W5M5.png) which has only one column. Second, I want to construct portfolios every 50 codes, and "r" is basically the average of the same date (the date is in "year-week" format. The result is like the listed portforlio number, each date and "r". It seems a really complicated task for me and can anyone help me...

Here is a sample original table.

| code | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2017-1 |
| 1 | 2017-2 |
| 1 | 2017-3 |
| 2 | 2017-1 |
| 2 | 2017-2 |
| 2 | 2017-3 |
| ... | ... |
| 3000 | 2017-3 |

And I have another table which is has the order code should be, like

| code |
| --- |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 564 |
| ... |

That's what I can thought of to explain myself...

Comment: please provide your example data as text (and only a minimal example sufficient to understand and reproduce the logic)

Comment: I tried to add two tables here...I'm not sure if they can be clear...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, and I tried to add some codes here.